# Synology Chat API python

Tags: python, chat, synology

I would like to use the chat API on Synology.

I already know the composition of the web link to act on the chat and send a message. 
This link works when I use it on a web browser:

```
http://"IP":"PORT"/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.Chat.External&method=incoming&version=2&token="TOKENKEY"&payload={"text":"Test message.\nDavid fait un test API"}
```

I receive this text: `Test message.David fait un test API`

Now I would like to use it in python but I can only use the 'urllib' & ‘json’ library.

Can you tell me how I can run on a '`urllib`' query with the value behind 'text' that can be changed dynamically?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json

TAGET_URL = http://"IP":"PORT"/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.Chat.External&method=incoming&version=2&token="TOKENKEY"

message='hello world'
body = 'payload=' + json.dumps({'text': message})
response = requests.post(TARGET_URL,body)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).